# KeyTyped ignora campo jTextField vacío en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema de lógica en esta programación de evento del `KeyTyped`.

Mi idea es que inicialmente el `button_limpiar` esté deshabilitado, y sólo se habilite cuando se escriba algo en el `jTextField`.
Mientras haya texto en el `jTextField`, el `button_limpiar` se habilita.

**El problema viene cuando escribo algo y borro el campo `jTextField` entero debido a que no se vuelve a deshabilitar el botón y sigue activo.**

¿A qué se debe?

**Al principio:**

```
initComponents();
button_limpiar.setEnabled(false);
```

**Código:**

```
private void textfield_DNIKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        if(textfield_DNI.getText().length()== 0){
            button_limpiar.setEnabled(false);
        }

        char numero = evt.getKeyChar();
        Character c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if((numero >= '0' || numero <= '9') || (Character.isLetter(c))){
            evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            button_limpiar.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
           evt.consume();
        }

        if(textfield_DNI.getText().length()>8){
            evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Así como ya lo haces, deberías cachar la tecla de borrado y deshabilitar el botón si la longitud del texto es cero.

Comment: ¿El `if((numero>='0'||numero<='9') || Character.isLetter(c)))` es para validar un patron (`\d{8}[a-zA-Z]`)?

Comment: Eso es, solo quiero permitir letras y números, y obviamente la tecla SUPR y retroceder.

Comment: @JohnnyTB El problema que tengo también es que si agrego el DNI con Control+V (para pegarlo en el campo jTextField) me sigue dando que el button_limpiar está deshabilitado cuando YA HAY tengo en el jTextField.

Comment: Cuál versión de java usas?

Comment: @E.Betanzos ¿Dónde se mira eso? ¿Tiene que ver con el Ctrl+V?

Comment: Depende, si estás trabajando desde un IDE debes buscar en la configuración del proyecto. No tiene nada que ver con el Ctrl+V, es para poder darte una solución.

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente `if((numero >= '0' || numero <= '9') || (Character.isLetter(c)))` causa tal problema; Ahora, un evento de `keyReleased` es bastante util, abajo explicaré:

```
private void textfield_DNIKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
  int len=textfield_DNI.getText().length();
  button_limpiar.setEnabled(len>0);
}

private void textfield_DNIKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
  /*if(textfield_DNI.getText().length()== 0){
    button_limpiar.setEnabled(false);
  }

  char numero = evt.getKeyChar();
  Character c = evt.getKeyChar();
  if((numero >= '0' || numero <= '9') || (Character.isLetter(c))){
    evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    button_limpiar.setEnabled(true);
  }else{
    evt.consume();
  }*/

  if(textfield_DNI.getText().length()>8){
    evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
  }
}
```

Cuando presionas y sueltas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> se desencadena un evento de `KeyReleased`, al contrario de `KeyTyped` que se ejecuta solo cuando se ha ingresado un caracter *Unicode*; por eso la importancia de cambiar el atributo del botón en el evento `KeyReleased`.

**PD:**
Hace un rato había dejado una respuesta la cual borré al pasar por alto ciertos detalles que hacian funcionar incorrectamente el programa, te ofrezco una disculpa :D

Comment: Sigo teniendo problemas con "si copio y pego un DNI con controlV"... imagínate que lo añado "12345678a", debería ponerse automáticamente "12345678A", pero me lo copia y pega con minúscula, no hace el toUpperCase();

Comment: Quizá te sirva forzar al `JTextField` para que solo admita letras en mayúscula, hay un ejemplo bastante sencillo http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DocumentFilterthatmapslowercaseletterstouppercase.htm